# Preventing app windows from changing workspaces when screen resolution changes

Tags: unity, xorg, resolution, workspaces

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

I have a Dell laptop with resolution 1400x900 attached to an external monitor with resolution 1920x1080.  When I attach to the external monitor I close the laptop lid and shut off the display there, and use the 1920x1080 resolution on the external.

Currently I have one row of 5 workspaces.  Like many users, I like specific apps to be in specific workspaces.  Web browser in workspace one, code IDE in workspace 2, terminals tailing log files in workspace 3, etc.

When I detach my laptop from the external monitor and open the laptop lid, the laptop screen becomes the active display with resolution 1400x900, and the workspace of all my apps has changed.  Most of them have moved to workspace 1.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: This is Compiz bug #763148 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/763148